# How to build a resnet with Keras that trains and predicts the subclass from the main class?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, hierarchical, deep-residual-networks

I would like go implement  a hierarchical resnet architecture. However, I could not find any solution for this. For example, my data structure is like:

- class A

  - Subclass 1
  - Subclass 2
  - ....
- class B

  - subclass 6
  - ........

So i would like to train and predict the main class and then the subclass of the chosen/predicted mainclass. Can someone provide a simple example how to do this with generators?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so would be to train multiple classifiers and build a hierarchical system by yourself.

One classifier detecting class A, B etc. After that make a new prediction for subclasses.

If you want only one single classifier:
What about just killing the first hierarchy of parent classes? Should be also quite easy. If you really want a model, where the hierarchy is learned take a look at Hierarchical Multi-Label Classification Networks.

Comment: Let say, we predict first the age group of a person (40,60), then the classifiers knows that the age is something between 40-60 years old and it will predict the apparent age 53. I cannot get the idea behind the implementation for this. So what you are saying is: train the network first on age groups. Then train multiple models, each based on a single age group(40-60) and finally merge those models to one model?

Comment: Yes, but for your example jus train directly on the age. The parent call (40-60) is just an artificial label, which can be obtained by averaging the prediction for classes 40-60.